# Could not find file application skin file error in Sitecore Jss 10.1

Tags: jss

For few users in Sitecore CM server while they are trying to access the content tree items, getting below attached error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skin text is missing for the custom created App route and the error occurs only for few users. If we add the text field value as "skin" shown below. The error will be resolved.

[image]